# Magento 2 form ui component ajax fieldset

Tags: magento2, ajax, uicomponent

I see that in the latest versions of Magento 2, the add/edit form for categories, blocks and pages are generated via a ui component form xml.
[Here is the example for cms pages](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_form.xml).
I want to use that for my own module like the big boys do.
I got most of the things figured out, but I wasn't able to add a fieldset that retrieves its contents via AJAX.
For example, I want to associate my custom entity "many to many" with the products, so I need a fieldset that contains nothing at first, but when is clicked it will retrieve the list of products via an ajax call.
I don't need the actual products grid code. All I need is a way to do an ajax call when clicking the fieldset header.

Comment: i will be at that point soon to have the same problem :) my first guess is to look into this: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/insert-listing.js

Comment: could be a good place to start, but I understand nothing from that file :)

Comment: haha yes that's mostly my problem with the ui-components: js :D

Comment: maybe this could be also helpull, will look into this later home: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/b1b05c887c705c3cc09a8abdd9e85db14f432c24/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/ui_component/etc/definition.xml#L322

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All I need is a way to do an ajax call when clicking the fieldset header.

Currently *Fieldset Ui Component* doesn't suport such ability: *click on fieldset* -> *load **content** via AJAX* .

### 1) You can implement it by yourself

Take a look on [*fieldset.js*](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/fieldset.js). It can be easily extended with custom behavior. In same maner as *fieldset.js* extends *collapsible.js*.

### 2) You can use *InsertListing Ui Component*

As was pointed above its js part is a *insert-listing.js* file.

#### Sample can be used like this:

```
<insertListing name="testListingInsert">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">cms_page_listing</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```

#### Where to put this?

In any *Form Ui Component* under `<fieldset>`'s or `<container>`'s.

#### What does component do?

It uses namespace `ns` as a locator for some *Ui Component*, loads it, and instantiate in place.

[`cms_page_listing`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml) is a name of configured Listing Ui Component.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try tomorrow and come back with the results.

Comment: nice, i was nearly that far ;) But I'm using the 2.0.2 where the insertListing is not implemented yet. I tried to add it manually by adding the component js file and then update the configuration files, but I seem to miss sth. maybe I' try in develop later

Comment: Yes, David, you are right: it miss something. There were changes in core js files to support such behavior :(

Comment: I wasn't able (yet) to achieve the desired behavior but this is just because of my capacity to understand what's going on in there. I will accept this answer as I did some tests as suggested and it and it looks like the way to go. I will accept the answer and post a full solution if/when I find one, but I really hope this will become a core feature soon.